# Roasted Peanuts

Tags: peanuts, dry

What is the best way to dry roast peanuts, Slow Dry Roasting or Quick Dry Roasting? Which will give maximum flavour and what will be the impact on the moisture content of peanuts & shelf life?

I use electric radiant heaters to dry roast peanuts but I find it does not give the same aroma as sand-roasting does. Does anyone know why, and if the aroma effects the final taste?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have "roasted" peanuts ( and other nuts) in a frying pan on a burner. Watch them closely and stir often , it produces good flavor. Adding oil is optional. They were used immediately so I don't know about shelf life.